# How to implement a reversed radial tilt shift effect in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs, image-manipulation

**What I'm creating**

I'm creating a JavaScript image manipulation app (using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) & HTML5 canvas) to build/re-render the canvas and place/drag objects onto it. After placing the objects it could export the data url and the image is manipulated.

**The feature that I would like to add**

I'm trying to implement a reversed radial tilt shift effect so certain spots in the picture could be "blurred out". What's the fastest way to achieve this through Fabric.js or just plain HTML5 canvas?

**This is an example of what I want to achieve**
[image: this is an example of what I want to achieve]

**What I've tried**

- Adding a Circle shape and trying to add an Blur/Convolute effect to
  it and then lowering the opacity => This didn't work in my case, I
  could only change the opacity attribute.
- Adding an image (from URL) and trying the same thing as the first
  point. => This didn't work in my case, I could only add a
  Blur/Convolute filter but not change the opacity.

Comment: Fastest you say? Just draw a circular path filled with a medium transparency white over the desired area. You can blur with pixel manipulation but its slooow.

Comment: @markE : i can't remember if shadowBlur applies to drawImage also... with proper clipping ( + offset trick ) that would be the answer.

Comment: @markE: The main thing I want to achieve is a blur so I think just transparency isn't going to the job.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you checked out [the stackblur script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758233/html5-canvas-blur-and-save/20766399#20766399)?

Comment: Yes I already checked StackBlur, but the problem is that I don't want to blur the canvas nor an image. I want to have an seethrough (low-opacity) object that blurs the image behind it.

Comment: StackBlur can handle the blurring and `context.clip` will handle restricting the blur to a certain area.

Comment: check my answer for an easy trick. You blur the image and use it as a patterns that move inverse to the circle. Please from screenshot i see you are using an old version of fabricjs ( stroke outside bouding box ) better you update.

Comment: markE thanks for the info @AndreaBogazzi I will try to apply your answer when I'm continuing development on this project. Also it's just a Photoshop shape not real Fabric js in the example :) but thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i can finish this demo later.

As you see i put your image as background.
Then i loaded the same image in a image element that i used to create a pattern for the circle.
Now, when the circle is moving i move the patterns offset so it looks like the image is the same as the background, but you are looking at the pattern.

Now imagine to use stackblur or fabricjs filters to blur the pattern image (just once)  and you should get the effect you desire.

some trick to compensate the scaling effect is required.

I will finish the demo later.
hope it gives you the help.

EDIT: i have serious cors issue here.
I do not know how to make a snippet with not local images.

here a working demo made with fabricjs:
http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/blur.html

Comment: Wow this is amazing thanks for the help and the awesome demo! This saves me a lot of time and could you point me in the right direction with "some trick to compensate the scaling effect is required."?

Comment: i added the scaling effect "hint" in the demo. I changed with an ellipse because thinking of blurring faces is more usefull. you know what? now rotation is missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) what did you change to scale effectively? And I think I'm going to disable rotation don't need that for now.

Comment: For what it's worth image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; only works when your server allows CORS so maybe the host you was trying to reach didn't

Comment: how to calculate the new width and height based on gesture events?